# How lower music volume on playing my app voice guidance in Android and after that increase music again?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, volume, audio-player, android-music-player, persistent-volumes

I am working on an android map app that like Waze or any other app uses voice guidance to guide people to their destination.

My problem is that I want if user play music with his/her phone **music volume decrease** and **voice guidance play with upper volume** and **after finishing guiding** user **music volume increase again** and get focus of speakers?

Is this can be down I searched a lot and saw some implementation of it but none of them helped me in this special condition.

Thanks all of you in advance.

Comment: **Is there anyone who can help me please ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

 mp = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
                            mp.setDataSource("/data/data/" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/rasa.wav");
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.start();
                            AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
                                    focusChange -> {
                        };
                            int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
                            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                                mp = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
                                mp.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer -> {
                                    am.abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener);
                                });
                                mp.setDataSource("/data/data/" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/rasa.wav");
                                mp.prepare();
                                mp.start();

                            }
```